# Accessing a class' member variable from another class

Tags: java

Consider this example:

```
public class FirstClass {
    public static int x;

   public static void main(String[] args){
     x = 5;
     SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
   }

   public int getX(){
     return x;
   }

}
//assume class SecondClass is in another File
public class SecondClass{}
```

I want to access variable x from class SecondClass and as far as I know there are two ways I can do this.

1. In SecondClass class I can simply do FirstClass.x ---> do stuff. IntelliJ allows me to do this since x has public visibility.
2. I make the constructor of SecondClass take a FirstClass fc as a parameter and then do this.fc = fc;  while having declared it as a member variable after class declaration. Then, in the main I change the instance of SecondClass to  SecondClass sc = new SecondClass(this);  And now I can have access in SecondClass through fc.getX();

What is the difference between the two as I have never seen an explanation in this scenario ?

Apologies if my example is not abstract enough but I tried to make it as much as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FirstClass {
    int x;
    ...... 
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

There is no maggic. it's by java specification.
[Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> The four access levels are −
>
> - Visible to the package, the default. No modifiers are needed.
> - Visible to the class only (private)
> - Visible to the world (public)
> - Visible to the package and all subclasses (protected)

your case  `int x;` has default access. All classes in some package have access to it.

> public int getX()

you can get x variable everywhere by in your project.

FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
int value = fc.getX();

You should use exactly this (call method instead of direct x) approach in 90% cases outside of your class and 10% getX() - inside class. There might be cases with testing , some extra logic for getX() -- but it's in common practice , not in your case

Comment: You said sc.getX(); but the getter belongs to FirstClass !

As for the visibility, thanks I understood that.

Comment: So you are suggesting to simply create an FirstClass instance in the main method and access x with the getter from there ? If yes, how does that help me when I want to access it from SecondClass

Comment: When you use static and public access  or default you have diract access to your variable. If it's simple program you can do that. But you can change x varialbe from everywhere in you program and it' not good

Comment: Get method give you access to x but you cant change it. It's read access. To have write access you should add set method

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access variable `x` from Second Class by `FirstClass.x` because I think you have declared `x` as static. Otherwise, you cannot access like that. Then you have to create an object of First Class then you have to access that variable `x`.
2. Don't pass the class in the constructor of Second Class. Just pass the variable `x`. This will be better. If we pass the class then we can do so many things from Second Class. For that reason, we will provide those data which are needed in Second Class.

   SecondClass sc = new SecondClass(x);

Comment: You are correct. While abstracting this example from my program I have missed this. I have corrected  my original post.  Regarding your 2. comment, can you please elaborate on why it would be better ? Also, what if I want to access more than one variable ? Still better to pass them all and not the class itself ?

Comment: you dont need to make variable static if it's not constant; just write     PRIVATE int x; in this case you  restrict access to x variable outside class

Comment: variable x is accessed from static main method. So, the variable x must have to be static.

Comment: @curiosityisBliss , if you want to access more than one variables than you can also think of inheritance.